# how to map violation to Symfony form manually?

Tags: symfony

OrderType

```
$builder
    ->add('items', FormTypes\CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => OrderItemType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'label' => 'acme.form.order.items',
    ])
    ->add('channel', ChannelSelectType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'acme.form.order.channel',
    ])
```

OrderItemType

```
$builder
    ->add('service', ServiceSelectType::class, [
        'label' => 'acme.form.order_item.service',
    ])
    ->add('product', ProductSelectType::class, [
        'label' => 'acme.form.order_item.product',
    ])
    ->add('quantity', FormTypes\IntegerType::class, [
        'label' => 'acme.form.order_item.quantity',
    ]);
```

## How to map the error to OrderItemType product field?

the order item is valid when a product is applied to a specific channel. however we have no way to get the submited channel in OrderItemType,
because child form type is submmited before its parent. so $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()->getChannel() is empty. the only way I have
is to validate order item in OrderType, or create a validator which is added to Order class. the problem is how can I map the error to OrderItemType product field.

```
$orderItems = $order->getItems();
$channel = $order->getChannel();

foreach($orderItems as $index => $orderItem) {
    $product = $orderItem->getProduct();
    if (!$this->isProductAvailableForChannel($channel, $product)) {
        $message = sprintf('product %ss is not available for channel "%s"', $product->getName(), $channel->getName());
    }


    if (null !== $message) {
        $this->context
                ->buildViolation($this->constraint->message)
                ->setParameter($message)
                ->atPath("items.children[$index].product")  // this doesn't work, the error will be added to root form.
                ->addViolation()
            ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to get the channel on the pre submit event (`Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`)
And there you can add your channel based validation for the order item

```
$addItems = function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $options = [];

    if (is_array($data) && array_key_exists('channel', $data)) {
        $options['constraints'] = [
            new OrderItemConstraint(['channel' => $data['channel']])
        ];
    }

    $form->add('items', FormTypes\CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => OrderItemType::class,
        'entry_options' => $options,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'label' => 'acme.form.order.items',
    ]);
};

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $addItems);
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $addItems);
```